# I(variable_1/variable_2) in R regression

Tags: r

```
R> data("FoodExpenditure", package = "betareg")
R> fe_lm <- lm(I(food/income) ~ income + persons, data = FoodExpenditure)
```

From what I understand `I(food/income)` creates a new variable which is the ratio of food over income, is it correct? Are there any other combinations (functions) possible?

Answer (score 2):

Observe that these two results are the same

```
# transformation in formula
lm(I(food/income) ~ income + persons, data = FoodExpenditure)
# Call:
# lm(formula = I(food/income) ~ income + persons, data = FoodExpenditure)
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)       income      persons  
#    0.341740    -0.002469     0.025767  


# transformation in data
dd <- transform(FoodExpenditure, ratio=food/income)
lm(ratio ~ income + persons, data = dd)
# Call:
# lm(formula = ratio ~ income + persons, data = dd)
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)       income      persons  
#    0.341740    -0.002469     0.025767
```

The `I()` function in a  formula with `lm()` allows you to perform any function of the variables that you like. (Just make sure the function doesn't change the number of rows otherwise you can't fit the model properly.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes and Yes.

Other possible combinations and operators are given in the documentation for formula `?formula`. What is below is mostly taken from it.

> **:** denotes interactions between the terms
>
> ***** operator denotes factor crossing: ‘a*b’ interpreted as ‘a+b+a:b’.
>
> **^** operator indicates
>        crossing to the specified degree.  For example ‘(a+b+c)^2’ is
>        identical to ‘(a+b+c)*(a+b+c)’ which in turn expands to a formula
>        containing the main effects for ‘a’, ‘b’ and ‘c’ together with
>        their second-order interactions.
>
> **%in%** operator indicates
>        that the terms on its left are nested within those on the right.
>        For example ‘a + b %in% a’ expands to the formula ‘a + a:b’.
>
> **-** operator removes the specified terms, so that ‘(a+b+c)^2 -
>        a:b’ is identical to ‘a + b + c + b:c + a:c’.  It can also used to
>        remove the intercept term: when fitting a linear model ‘y ~ x - 1’
>        specifies a line through the origin.  A model with no intercept
>        can be also specified as ‘y ~ x + 0’ or ‘y ~ 0 + x’.
>
> **arithmetic expressions** -   While formulae usually involve just variable and factor names,
>        they can also involve arithmetic expressions.  The formula ‘log(y)
>        ~ a + log(x)’ is quite legal.
>
> **I()**    To avoid this confusion, the function ‘I()’ can be used to bracket
>        those portions of a model formula where the operators are used in
>        their arithmetic sense.  For example, in the formula ‘y ~ a +
>        I(b+c)’, the term ‘b+c’ is to be interpreted as the sum of ‘b’ and
>        ‘c’.